# Ext.js4 - Show plain text returned from Java servlet

Tags: servlets, extjs4, plaintext

I am using Ext.js4 and Java servlets.  When the user clicks a button on a panel, I execute a Servlet which in turn executes another application, which produces a log file in .txt format.  I know the servlet and the other application are being executed.  I want the servlet to return the contents of the .txt file, which Ext.js should in turn display as straight text on a separate "Log" tab.  Do I need a store and model for something like this?  Note that the data returned by the servlet is just text, not JSON or HTML, and special characters (which would preclude the use of JSON or HTML) may be included in that text.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post some code.  Considering the vast amount of different ways to accomplish that, you'll need to give the community a little more context to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need a store and model for this.

I would write a servlet that simply returns the contents of the .txt file.

Then use the [Ext.Ajax class](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax) to create a request to this servlet and save the text as a variable.

Then you can just do: `logTab.update(theText)` to fill your tab with the contents of the .txt file (where `logTab` is your tab you want updated).

For example:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '../textServlet',
    success: function(response){
        var theText = response.responseText;
        logTab.update(theText); // or however you define your tab
    }
});
```

Comment: Geronimo: That took care of it.  Thank you very much for taking the time to respond.